# Check string is in format by using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of strings such as:

> "HARMONICMYANMARIBC201"  MOVIE  11711705254 20150910100938 353
>   1000000/29970029 "NEW YORK_PRORES.MOV-PRORES"  MOVIE  6091966623
>   20150915140421 8424 100/2997

and I need to check that they are in the following format and thus valid:

`"<string>"<2 spaces><string><2 spaces><long><1 space><long><1 space><int><1 space><long>/<long>`

I have little experience with `Regex` expressions and this one I am stumped at.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Whoever downvoted, can they explain so I can restructure the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example string doesn't match the description of the syntax you've given. But assuming your description is right, you could do it with:

```
"[^"]*"\s\s\w+\s\s\d+\s\d+\s[+-]?\d+\s\d+\/\d+
```

I'm not sure what the difference between `long` and `int` are either, in this context. Just to hint, I added the possibility of an optional sign to the `int`.

Check this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gD9bT2/1)

Regards

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! Thank you for posting a link to Regex101 as well. Ill use that in future!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex:

```
^"[^"]+"  \w+  \d+ \d+ \d+ \d+/\d+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: How did you make that image? :O

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this one:

```
^\S+\s{2}\S+\s{2}\d+\s{1}\d+\s{1}\d+\s{1}\d+\/\d+
```